# Buffer-local input history for read-from-minibuffer

Tags: minibuffer, buffer-local, history-variables

I've been trying to create a command that, when run, calls another function (`my-function`) which reads from the minibuffer and does some processing on the input. I want the command history for this command (`my-command`) to be buffer-local, so that each buffer will have a separate input history.

The input history is supposed to be stored in variable `my-hist`. Here's a summarized version of my code:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun my-function (hist)
  (read-from-minibuffer "> " nil nil nil 'hist))

(defvar my-hist nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-hist)

(defun my-command ()
  (interactive)
  (add-to-history 'my-hist (my-function 'my-hist)))
```

I've found that after executing `my-command` from two different buffers, their input history is shared, for some reason. Using `M-p` and `M-n` I can go back and forwards through all the inputs I've entered from any of the two buffers. However, if I inspect `my-hist` using `M-:`, the input history appears to be correct for each buffer.

Could this be related to how `read-from-minibuffer` looks up the value pointed at by symbol `'hist`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm actually trying to do is ... calling `read-number` from a separate function (my-command) with a buffer-local variable as HIST.

As `read-number` doesn't have its own history list, you could let-bind `minibuffer-history` to your buffer-local history list around your call to `read-number`.

```el
(defvar-local local-history nil
  "Buffer-local history.")

(defun my-command ()
  "Read a number."
  (interactive)
  (message "Number was %f"
           (let ((minibuffer-history local-history))
             (prog1 (read-number "Num: ")
               (setq-local local-history minibuffer-history)))))
```

That `setq-local` is needed because, following the `read-number` call, `local-history` might only be the cdr of the `minibuffer-history` list (i.e. if a new value was pushed to the history), so it needs to be updated to the current value.

Comment: This does the trick and answers my original question, thanks. Additionally, we may have found a problem with `read-from-minibuffer` when a buffer-local variable is used for `hist`.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```lisp
(defvar my-hist nil)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'my-hist)

(defun my-function (hist)
  (read-from-minibuffer "> " nil nil nil hist))

(defun my-command ()
  (interactive)
  (add-to-history 'my-hist (my-function 'my-hist)))
```

Don't quote `hist` when you pass it to `read-from-minibuffer`. You want to pass its *value*, e.g. the symbol `my-hist`, and not the result of evaluating `'hist`, which is the symbol `hist`.

But I agree with you about using `M-p` etc. Function `read-from-minibuffer` apparently doesn't use the buffer-local value of the history variable - either for access or for updating (adding to it).

That would also explain why, to add to the buffer-local value you need to explicitly use `add-to-history`, passing the value of the input that was read.

Normally (i.e., if the history var is not buffer-local), you would just invoke `(my-function 'my-hist)` in `my-command` - `read-from-minibuffer` automatically adds the read input to the history variable. But doing that when the var is buffer-local doesn't update it.

Seems like a bug.  But this is longstanding behavior (I see it back to Emacs 22, and I see the fact that it doesn't work without `add-to-history` even back to Emacs 20, which doesn't have `add-to-history`). So I'm probably missing something. Hopefully someone else will enlighten us.

(`completing-read` behaves the same way.)

Good question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thanks for the tip regarding `'hist` and `hist` as well, that had me confused when I initially wrote it.

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug: [#38282](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=38282)

Comment: That was actually the wishlist item I filed before asking here about my problem, I'll file a separate one for `read-from-minibuffer` separately!

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it buffer-locally:

```
(defvar-local my-hist-symbol nil)

(defun my-function ()
  (unless my-hist-symbol
    ;; Create the buffer's history symbol.
    (setq-local my-hist-symbol (make-symbol "my-hist")))
  (read-from-minibuffer "> " nil nil nil my-hist-symbol))

(defun my-command ()
  (interactive)
  (my-function))

(defun my-show-buffer-history ()
  (interactive)
  (if (null my-hist-symbol)
      (message "No history yet")
    (message "%s" (symbol-value my-hist-symbol))))
```

Comment: Do you think there would be a way to have `my-function` receive the history input list by parameter? What I'm actually trying to do is modify `read-number` in `subr.el`, to add a `hist` parameter for it (that would be my `my-function`). Then, I'm calling `read-number` from a separate function (`my-command`) with a buffer-local variable as HIST.

Comment: Your comment should really be a separate question for emacs.SE, I think. It may be the "real" question you had, but it is a different question.

Comment: @stefan: Is the need to do things that way because `read-from-minibuffer` doesn't consider the buffer which is current when you invoke `my-command` to be the current buffer, for purposes of getting the value of the variable (and so it uses the global default value)? It's not clear to me why `read-from-minibuffer` doesn't already DTRT (in terms of expectation), using the local value of the var in that buffer.

Comment: @Drew: AFAICT, the reason why you need this is because `read-from-minibuffer` (or more specifically `read_minibuf` in `minibuf.c`) modifies the history var *before* exiting the minibuffer so it affects the value local to the minibuffer.  I can't think of a good reason for it, so it might qualify as a bug.

Comment: @Stefan: OK, thanks. You'd probably be the best-placed to file such a bug. Seems like, at the very least, users should not have to jump through hoops to be able to use buffer-local history variables. Or else maybe something about the impossibility/difficulty should be documented.

Comment: @Drew: I'm not affected by this bug, so no I'm not best placed to report it

Comment: @Drew you're right, maybe I should have been more specific with my question. My idea is to fix https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=38282 by adding a buffer-local history list for `goto-line`. To do that I was planning on modifying `read-number` to add a `hist` parameter.

Comment: I can file the bug report! How about something like: "read-from-minibuffer does not work with buffer-local variables as input history"?

Comment: @Federico: Sounds good.  But include the code you tried to use and an explanation for why you want those vars to be buffer-local.

Comment: Done: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=38317